# ListView not updating properly during search?

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I have an EditText in my ActionBar. The problem is, when I enter text, it searches through my ListView properly and updates the ArrayList, but it seems to think that my ListView is still the same size as before. So when I scroll down the ListView, it crashes after the last item in the new ArrayList.

Here is the `onTextChanged` function:

```
@Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
            if (charSequence.length() > 0) {
                adapter.updateData(songList, charSequence);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        getListView().refreshDrawableState();
                        getListView().invalidateViews();
                    }
                }); //...
          } }
```

Here is my custom `updateData` function:

```
public void updateData(ArrayList<Song> originalList, CharSequence searchText) {

    itemsArrayList = new ArrayList<Song>();
    String search = searchText.toString();

    for (Song song : originalList) {
        if (search.equalsIgnoreCase((String) song.getName().subSequence(0, searchText.length()))
                || search.equalsIgnoreCase((String) song.getArtist().subSequence(0, searchText.length()))
                || song.getLyrics().contains(search)) {

           this.itemsArrayList.add(song);
        }
    }
}
```

Update: the error in LogCat is "invalid index"

```
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 45, size is 45
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
```

Comment: Did you override `getCount()` so that the adapter know the new count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your adapter.getCount() method look like? You need to override it. Also, don't add to the ArrayList, add to the adapter as a matter of style  (You don't have to call notifyDataSetChanged() then).

Comment: Thanks, overriding adapter.getCount() fixed it. Not sure why I didn't consider that!